# Git does not use SSH key (Windows)

Tags: windows, git, pycharm, gitlab, ssh-keys

I created a SSH key for my GitLab repository and when I test it with SSH it does work and asks for the passphrase:

```
>ssh -T git@gitlab.lrz.de
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\[username]/.ssh/id_ed25519':
Welcome to GitLab, @000[...]!
```

I also used

```
>git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.lrz.de:000[...]/project.git
```

without errors. However, when I try to commit and push to the repository, then Git asks for the Password of `git@gitlab.lrz.de` and not for the passphrase of the SSH key.

According to the Docs (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/), you can set the ssh key in the config file `~/.ssh/config`. So I created a text file in this directory with this content:

```
Host gitlab.lrz.de
 HostName gitlab.lrz.de
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

It still does not work and I am not sure if it even uses this config file. I was able to get everything running on a Linux server but not on this Windows computer. I tried it via command line and via Pycharm.

```
>git --version
git version 2.35.1.windows.1
```

Comment: I want to try to explain what apparently happened: I have a home in its usual location (`C:\Users\username`) and when creating `ssh` keys, or when using `ssh`, this location is used. However, each user also has a home on another server and apparently git interpreted the `~` as this one (`P:`). And there is actually also a `.ssh` folder there and a config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the ssh command used by git in the git config and then pass your key when using any git command.

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519"
```

Comment: It did not immeadiately work, but I got an error message, that helped me! It said, that `Warning: Identity file /p//.ssh/id_ed25519 not accessible: No such file or directory.` So I used the complete path to the key file and then it worked with this command. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

@kipy is nearly correct...

The issue is that git bundles its own SSH executable with it, and as in Windows (at least historically) the native OpenSSH client was optional, git won't acknowledge it by default. As a result of this, when you're doing things like:

`ssh-add <my-key>`

In Powershell (or whatever), that's not actually the SSH client that your git commands are using.

This complicates things further as, like me, you'll type:

`ssh -T git@github.com`

See the "Success!" message, and then scratch your head, wondering why `git clone git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git` gives a `(public key)` error. I guess the clue is pretty clear, but not obvious... In one you run `ssh` directly, the other one you run `git`, which then calls 'ssh' by proxy.

The correct command to solve this, is to tell your git installation (via its config) which version of SSH you want it to use, so:

`git config --global core.sshCommand C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe`

This will then prompt all `git` commands to use the same SSH client that your `ssh` command does.

This also allows you to use different keys for different remotes, as well as working in all terminals/applications.

---

**NOTE**: The above assumes that OpenSSH for Windows is installed via the Windows Optional Programs process, which is most likely the case, but just to be sure, you can open a PowerShell window, and run:

`(Get-Command ssh).Path`

Which will output something like:

`C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`

If it doesn't output that, then replace the last part of the `git config` command above with this output instead.

Comment: that should be mentioned in the github docs !!! thats the problem i faced when trying to use my keys via agent, basically the git clone have not seen the global agent as it was using its local copy of ssh as you mentioned. perfect answear

Comment: just for fun: ` git config --global core.sshCommand $( Get-Command ssh ).Path.replace("\", "/")`

Answer (score 3):

When you have one or more ssh-keys on Windows, for pushing to separate Git-repositories:

c:\Users\anbj\.ssh\config:

```
    Host github.com
        Hostname github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile /c/Users/anbj/.ssh/id_ed25519_client_A

    Host otherhub.com
        Hostname otherhub.com
        User git
        IdentityFile /c/Users/anbj/.ssh/id_ed25519_client_B
```

*NOTE* Do not write a colon ( as in c: ). Confusingly this will work when running a test such as

```
    ssh -vT github.com
```

... but will fail once you got to do a Git push as in

```
    git push -u origin develop
```

Removing the colon and using an absolute path is what worked for me using  Git 2.36.0.windows.1 on Windows 11.

Comment: Not sure how `/c/Users/....` is supposed to work. I tested `/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. First one did **not** work. Second one did work.

Answer (score 0):

in PyCharm try navigating to `VCS -> Git -> Remotes` and make sure that the URL configured there is aligned with the SSH URL (u can see the ssh URL when navigating to the repo via the browser and clicking on the clone button)